# Child doesn't execute after double fork in systemd

Tags: c, linux, fork, daemon, systemd

I have this C code to daemonize a systemd service:

```
static void daemon_me(char *my_name) {
    pid_t new_pid;
    struct sigaction sig_act;
    int i;
    int f0, f1, f2;
    int my_mask;
    umask(0);

    if((new_pid = fork()) < 0) {
        err_exit("%s: Errore sulla fork", my_name);
    }
    else if(new_pid != 0) {
        exit(0);
    }
    syslog(LOG_CRIT, "PRINT0 pid %d", new_pid);
    setsid(); 

    if((new_pid = fork()) < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_CRIT, "PRINT1 pid %d", new_pid);
        err_exit("%s: Errore sulla fork", my_name);
    }
    else if(new_pid != 0) {
        syslog(LOG_CRIT, "PRINT2 pid %d", new_pid);
        exit(0);
    }
    syslog(LOG_CRIT, "PRINT3 pid %d", new_pid);
```

and it doesn't execute the child process after the second fork(). the log is:

```
PRINT0 pid 0
WAN_Application.out: PRINT2 pid 3009
```

if i run it manually it works fine:

```
PRINT0 pid 0
PRINT2 pid 3080
PRINT3 pid 0
```

Why it happens only using systemd?

It should have the same behaviour

EDIT: full example

```
#include <string.h>                             /* strrchr, strerror, strcat, memset */
#include <syslog.h>                             /* openlog, syslog, closelog, setlogmask */
#include <stdlib.h>                             /* strtol, exit */
#include <stdio.h>                              /* fputs, vsnprintf, snprintf, fflush */
#include <sys/types.h>                          /* umask, open, accept, setsockopt */
#include <sys/stat.h>                           /* umask, open */
#include <sys/resource.h>                       /* getrlimit */
#include <sys/socket.h>                         /* accept, shutdown, setsockopt */
#include <stdarg.h>                             /* va_start */
#include <unistd.h>                             /* fork, setsid, chdir. close, dup, sync, sleep */
#include <signal.h>                             /* sigemptyset, sigaction */
#include <fcntl.h>                              /* open */
#include <sys/mman.h>                           /* mlockall */
#include <sys/un.h>                             /* sockaddr_un */
#include <sys/shm.h>                            /* shmdt, shmctl */

#define MAX_MSG_SIZE (512)

char main_strbuff[MAX_MSG_SIZE];

static void term_handler(int signo) {
    syslog(LOG_CRIT, "term_handler: rcv %d.", signo);
    closelog();
    exit(0);

} /* term_handler */

static void err_handle(int has_errno, int my_errno, const char *my_args,
                        va_list my_list) {
    char my_string[MAX_MSG_SIZE];           /* Buffer di diagnostica */

    vsnprintf(my_string, MAX_MSG_SIZE, my_args, my_list);
    if(has_errno) {
        snprintf(my_string + strlen(my_string), MAX_MSG_SIZE - strlen(my_string), ":%s", strerror_r(my_errno, main_strbuff, MAX_MSG_SIZE));
    }
    strcat(my_string, "\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    fputs(my_string, stderr);
    fflush(NULL);

}

static void err_exit(const char *my_args, ...) {
    va_list args_list;

    va_start(args_list, my_args);
    err_handle(0, 0, my_args, args_list);
    va_end(args_list);

    exit(1);

}

static void err_print(const char *my_args, ...) {
    va_list args_list;

    va_start(args_list, my_args);
    err_handle(0, 0, my_args, args_list);
    va_end(args_list);
}

static void daemon_me(char *my_name) {
    struct rlimit file_lim;
    pid_t new_pid;          
    struct sigaction sig_act;
    int i;                  
    int f0, f1, f2;         
    int my_mask;            

    umask(0);

    sig_act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sigemptyset(&sig_act.sa_mask);
    sig_act.sa_flags = 0;
    if(sigaction(SIGHUP, &sig_act, NULL) < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_CRIT, "Impossibile ignorare SIGHUP");
        exit(1);
    }

    sig_act.sa_handler = term_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sig_act.sa_mask);
    sig_act.sa_flags = SA_INTERRUPT;
    if(sigaction(SIGTERM, &sig_act, NULL) < 0) {
        /* Errore di sistema */
        syslog(LOG_CRIT, "Impossibile configurare SIGTERM");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((new_pid = fork()) < 0) {
        err_exit("%s: Errore sulla fork", my_name);
    }
    else if(new_pid != 0) {
        exit(0);
    }

    setsid(); 

    if((new_pid = fork()) < 0) {
        err_exit("%s: Errore sulla fork", my_name);
    }
    else if(new_pid != 0) {
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    daemon_me("programNAME");

    syslog(LOG_CRIT, "Success!");
    while(1);
}
```

systemd service keep restarting itself. Launch it manually and it will work.

EDIT2: OS info
/etc/issue:
Linux COM-Blade-0 4.19.0-25-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.289-1 (2023-07-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux

EDIT3: I tried to comment from `if(chdir("/") < 0)` to the end of function but nothing changed.

EDIT 4: new example the SIGTERM handling. while lunching with systemd it prints: `term_handler: rcv 15` which is SIGTERM

Comment: Sidenote: `int daemon(int nochdir, int noclose);` - _"The `daemon()` function is for programs wishing to detach themselves from the controlling terminal and run in the background as system daemons."_

Comment: i know, but it doesn't do the double-fork. this is legacy code and i cant' change it too much...

Comment: glibcs `daemon()` does only one `fork()` but you could do `daemon; setsid; fork` to simplify what you are doing.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: Can you please show a [mre]? I just tested your snippet and it works for me.

Comment: i added my non working code. maybe it's OS dependent?

Comment: Could be, I'm on Fedora38, kernel 6.4.6. I now tested your non-working code as a service too and it daemonizes just fine but then directly after that there's a `systemd[1]: syl.service: Deactivated successfully.` syslog message. Will dig some more later.

Comment: Aha: `for(i = 0; i < file_lim.rlim_max; i++) { close(i); }` - That's the problem. Remove that and it'll get further.

Comment: Does systemd get upset because the process it created exits?  You ignore SIGHUP eventually but the signal might be sent sooner.  I tight be SIGTERM instead of SIGHUP.  Should the original poses wait for its child to exit before exiting itself?  No answers — only food for thought.

Comment: I updated the example handling SIGTERM earlier. seems like it receive it while using systemd

Comment: @Davide Did you try to only close file descriptors that your service opened?

Comment: @TedLyngmo in the updated example i don't handle file descriptors and i still can reproduce the issue

Comment: Ok, I don't have time to figure out all details right now, but you get a SIGTERM when the parent dies and then you handle that by dying. If you just ignore the SIGTERM signal, the service will stay up and log "Done" in this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/rj55MjGT1).

Comment: What service type are you using? Is it Type=forking or Type=simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `Type=forking` service, systemd treats the **initial process exiting** as an indication that startup is done and the service is now ready – whatever is left becomes the main service process.

At this point, the service is 'active', therefore if *that* process then exits (even if it's part of double-forking), systemd takes that as an indication of the entire service stopping.

Solution 1: **Do not use double-fork in systemd.** You literally don't need it. When your process is run from a service manager, it's a daemon from the very beginning – it's already in "background"; there is no tty to detach from; there is no session to setsid() away from; there are no FDs to close – double-forking or daemonizing serves no purpose here.

So you can just `#if 0` all of the code and switch the .service unit to  `Type=simple`.

*(Ideally though you should use `Type=notify` and call `sd_notify(0, "READY=1")` from libsystemd when the daemon is, in fact, ready. This is still the same as Type=simple in that it needs no forking, but has the advantage of more accurate monitoring, needing only minimal changes. Later, you could even add some `sd_notify(0, "STATUS=Brewing coffee (%d done)", progress)` and such...)*

Solution 2: Create a pipe before forking, then have the parent process *wait before exiting* until the grandchild sends it a 'ready' indication over the pipe. This is the traditional method and will improve the service's behavior for *all* service managers (including sysv init), not just systemd.

Comment: Thanks, i implemented solution 1. it think it's the easiest and cleaniest one